# GSM library_ all examples ar working except GPRS?

Tags: gsm, web-server

i am using arduino uno and sim808. i connected the sim808 to pins 2,3 on arduino uno and used GSM library. i tested all examples: make and receive a call or messages. the part of GPRS initialization is not working after many tries in changing APN and pin number.
i want to use the arduino as a webserver exactly as the example includded in the library.
any one can help?
thanks,
https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/GSM

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem I solved it by moving the jumper wires on the shield(if you are using one) to SW serial. if that doesn't work try testing it with AT commands